# Another car hit my car, impact was mostly to front wheel and fender

Tags: bmw, alignment

Hi i got hit hard on wheel and tire, alignment is off, both front wheels point in diff directions, can the be fixed to oem perfection, or is the car a write off, 2018 Bmw M4 ? Other parties insurance is taking care of the issue, I would like to be able to track the car and have been known to drive fast, I hope to never have issues with alignment or tracking.

Comment: I believe that a car as expensive and new as 2018 BMW M4 will be repaired.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be fixed (anything can be fixed if you throw enough money at it...), it may include chassis straightening (expensive) and any replacement parts, suspension, steering etc

If the other party's insurance is doing the work, they may deem it too expensive to repair on economic grounds and pay you what they say it is worth...

If they go ahead with the repair then you should get it checked by a competent independent BEFORE accepting the vehicle - you will have to pay for this check yourself.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i just have grave concerns if the car is going to track to the right or be straight, for the speeds i like, I purchased this car for a reason, and if that reason is unfilled it is of little use to me. i hope for total loss, but am concerned about settlement. Repair and return to me doesnt sound too good right now thanks for the reply.